# Hermitian conjugates of Dirac equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, spinors, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices

I am given the following Dirac equations:
$$
(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} - m)u_s(p) = 0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(1)
$$
$$
(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} + m)v_s(p) = 0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(2)
$$
where u are the positive energy solutions and v are negative energy solutions. I have to prove the following:
$$
\bar{u}_s(p)(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} - m) = 0       \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(3)
$$
$$
\bar{v}_s(p)(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} + m) = 0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(4)
$$
where$\;\bar{u}_s(p) = u_s^{\dagger}(p)\gamma^0$ and $\;\bar{v}_s(p) = v_s^{\dagger}(p)\gamma^0$

Here i what i have tried:
I take hermitian conjugate of eqn (1),
$$
u_s^\dagger(p)(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} - m)^\dagger=0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(5)
$$
$$
u_s^\dagger(p)((\gamma^{\mu})^\dagger p_{\mu} - m)=0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(6)
$$

$$
u_s^\dagger(p)(\gamma^{0} \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{0} p_{\mu} - m)=0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(7)
$$

$$
\bar{u}_s(p)(\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{0} p_{\mu} - m)=0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;eqn\;(8)
$$

How do i get eqn (3) from eqn (8)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. There is a mistake in going from eq. (7) to eq. (8). The correct way of proving Eq. (3) from Eq. (1) is to take the Bar of Eq. (1), or equivalently to multiply your Eq. (7) with a $\gamma^0$ from the right.

Comment: you factor out $\gamma^0$ but the mass term doesn't contain a gamma at the moment

Comment: You forgot  to add a gamma to the $m$ when pulling the $\gamma^0$ out of the parenthesis when going from from 7 to 8.